# Navigation bar is moving up to statusbar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a `viewController`. Which does not have `navigationBar.` I am pushing another `viewController` that has `navigationBar.` Which is going up 
I am using following code to show the `navigationBar`

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
```

Comment: Its not very clear to understand what you asking for.can you post screenshot of the problem.

Comment: I have attached the image but it is not visible here   . this is the link for image https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHF8g.png

Comment: let me know the code works?

Comment: code and output screencast updated....

Comment: what you mean not working. specify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you trying to hide `navigationBar` in `firstVC` and show it in `secondVC`.

Try following method into your `firstVC` and make sure you embedded your `firstVC` with `navigationController`.

Your **storyBoard** flow layout should be look like below...

[image]

**Implement below method in firstVC.**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)   
}
```

Output:**Updated**

[image]

Comment: If you click on the back button it works if you simply swipes to go back you can see the visible navigation bar going up.