# UITabBarController selected item show navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm making an application using UITabBarController and UINavigationController.
The view controller diagram look like this:

```
TabBar Controller > Navigation Controller > View Controller
```

At the first view controller I'm set navigation bar to hidden. But when I clicked on TabBar items to show other view controller then clicked back to first view controller the navigation bar was shown. Whenever I added in all other view controllers:

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

Anyone know how to set my navigation bar in first view controller to always hide? Please help.
Thank in advance.

Comment: To do so, each of your view controllers should be embedded inside a navigation controller. after that add all navigation controller to tab bar controller. with single navigation controller, its really complicated .

Comment: check the answer may helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120482/navigation-bar-is-moving-up-to-statusbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are in some view controller have to use this method:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

To hide Navigationbar in any viewController :

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];   // Will hides Navigationbar  
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated]; // Will shows Navigationbar
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

**Swift**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple tabs at the bottom who follows the structure:

Controller > Navigation Controller > View Controller

Then to hide the navigation bar in the first view controller, you need to use the following code

```
// TO HIDE NAVIGATION BAR in the first view controller

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}

// TO SHOW NAVIGATION BAR in other view controllers
```

If you want all other views should have a navigation bar visible, you could use viewWillDisappear to set it to visible again.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: I tried @Lal Krishna answer and it's worked. But also thank you for the help.