# How to keep a parent viewController from inheriting transparent navigationBar property of a child viewController?

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationbar, transparency, xcode8

I was able to set the `navigationBar` for a `detailedViewController` to be transparent by using:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

and this works fine. However when I link the `detailedViewController` to the initial `firstViewController` through a segue, both the parent `firstViewController` and the child `detailedViewController` have transparent `navigationBar` properties.

Question: how can I keep the parent `firstViewController` from inheriting this transparency property from the child `detailedViewController`?

Comment: Do you actually want the navigation bar to be transparent or do you just want it to hide?

Comment: if you want this property for whole app then set UINavigationBar appearance

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with inheritance, the `firstViewController` and `detailedViewController` simply share the `navigationController` they are presented in, so changes made to it from within `detailedViewController` affect its presentation for the parent controller as well. Consider styling and re-styling the `navigationBar` using `UINavigationControllerDelegate.navigationController:willShow:` or the respective controllers' `viewWillAppear:` if you want to do it from code

Comment: crizzis, I tried setting `navigationBar` transparency property under `viewWillAppear` for the `detailedViewController` however, it still affects the parent `firstViewController`. I'll give the `UINavigationControllerDelegate.navigationController:willShow:` a shot to see if this works ...

Comment: check this post may help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120482/navigation-bar-is-moving-up-to-statusbar/42909654#42909654

Comment: @Joe, this post doesn't answer my question. Real issue was being able to set the `navigationBar` to be transparent - that way we can still see the title of the navigation bar and not make it hidden. Thanks for sharing this though

Comment: check this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835420/navigationbar-delay-updating-bartintcolor-ios10/40255483#40255483

Comment: @Joe, this still doesn't work for me. My test app crashes when I use `isViewLoaded` in swift 3 -